# How do I add number of days from original dates in new column

Tags: sql, date, time, google-bigquery, intervals

Hopefully a quick one on BigQuery

I've tried intervals and days but can't quite seem to get what I want. For date row on the example table below I want and adjacent row in a new column that just adds 42 days to the original date and time (time is always 00:00:00 if that helps).

Desired output below:

| original_datetime | date_time_plus_42_days |
| --- | --- |
| 2016-04-01T00:00:00 | plus 42 days to left column |
| 2016-05-04T00:00:00 | plus 42 days to left column |
| 2018-05-17T00:00:00 | plus 42 days to left column |
| 2019-09-01T00:00:00 | plus 42 days to left column |
| 2016-04-01T00:00:00 | plus 42 days to left column |

Comment: Empty column in the desired output, really?

Comment: No - that's where I want the 42 days added. Sorry if that wasn't clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider also below approach with explicit use of interval data type

```
select original_datetime,
  original_datetime + interval 42 day as date_time_plus_42_days
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question

```
with your_table as (
  select datetime '2016-04-01T00:00:00' original_datetime union all
  select '2016-05-04T00:00:00' union all
  select '2018-05-17T00:00:00' union all
  select '2019-09-01T00:00:00' union all
  select '2016-04-01T00:00:00' 
)
```

output is

[image]

Benefit of using interval data type is that in one shot you can add multiple units - for example not just days but also hours as in example below

```
select original_datetime,
  original_datetime + make_interval(day => 42, hour => 5) as date_time_plus_42_days
from your_table
```

with output

[image]

Comment: Thank you - that's a very thorough explanation and walkthrough, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is called: `DATETIME_ADD`. It is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#datetime_add).

For instance:

```
WITH table AS (
     SELECT DATETIME("2016-04-01T00:00:00") AS datetime)
SELECT
  datetime,
  DATETIME_ADD(datetime, INTERVAL 42 DAY) as datetime_plus_42
FROM table;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, perfect.